# Using JTA in simple JDBC application

Tags: jdbc, transactions, jta

I have read on-line about JTA. Now, I want to implement it in a simple possible program.

I have the code below of JDBC, in which I am managing the transaction explicitly (by JDBC API's).

Code snippet:

```
    String ssnID = null;
    ssnID = "9";
    String sql;

    String sql_delete = null;
    sql_delete = "Delete from USER where ssnId = " + "9";

    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);                     <-------- (1)
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql_delete);
        //other code as part of transaction
    conn.commit();                                 <---------(2)
```

In above I am using JDBC API's for manual transaction management.

My question is, how can I use JTA for the transaction management? Is JTA transaction management different from what JDBC uses?

Any explanation to understand this would be of great help.

Comment: If you want to use JTA, you need to use an `XADataSource` for the connections.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Thanks for you reply, from which framework/ jar i get this?

Comment: You will also need a JTA implementation (eg [Bitronix](https://github.com/bitronix/btm), or another one). `XADataSource` implementations are - usually - part of the JDBC driver package.